# Define custom chapter

Tags: macros, chapters

I have having trouble defining a custom chapter "mybox" which I would like to be based upon the attributes of `\chapter` but called Box and numbered alphabetically.

Below is my code, the command `\mybox` is created but is identical to `\chapter`. The output and desired results are shown below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

%---- Define Box ----%        
\newcommand{\mybox}{\chapter}
%\renewcommand{\myboxname}{Box}    - Causes error
\newcounter{mybox}
\renewcommand\themybox{\Alph{mybox}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\mybox{Box A}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Shall this `Box` appear in the table of contents as well? Does it have subboxes (like `\section`?)Giving it a different name will not make it use the other counter then, by the way

Comment: It should do everything as a normal chapter, have sections (i.e. A.1,...) and appear in the TOC. Document structure would be e.g. Chapter 1, Chapter 2, Box A, Chapter 3, Box B, Chapter 4, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake completeness a shorter solution:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\let\chaptercopy\chapter
\newcommand*\userbox[2][]{%
  \begingroup
    \def\@chapapp{Box}
    \def\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}
    \color{green}
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
      \chaptercopy{#2}
    \else
      \chaptercopy[#1]{#2}
    \fi
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\userbox{My fancy box}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

[image: showcase_toc]

Comment: In the TOC, this appears as Chapter A. How can I have the entry appear as Box A followed by Chapter 1, etc.?

Comment: @user2568648 -- In my example the TOC shows simply "A ..." which, I guess, is acceptable. You must have activated some kind of tweak to the TOC in your version. Can you tell me what exactly that is?

Comment: I added the following above the definition `\newlength\mylength
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{Chapter~}
\settowidth\mylength{\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum{5em}}
\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\mylength}` to add the text "Chapter" before the numbers. Obviously this also adds before the letters corresponding to box chapters. I was wondering if I could distinguish between the two.

Comment: @user2568648 -- all those commands are new, thus can't be redefined. I guess you are doing lots of patching that is obscure to me and everybody watching this question as it is not in your MWE above. Anyways, your last mentioned issue is definitively indipendent from the question asked here. That means: you can either ask a new question regarding your new issue or (better) first search TeX.SX as I suspect that this exact question alredy got solved here.

Comment: This is intriguengly short -- too short -- try this with `\label{foo}` for the userbox and the `\ref` will be empty (and `hyperref` will complain as well!) I had something pretty similar in my first version and realized that there was some errors.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- ouch, right now Im on my way home and cant really check it, but I think I see why you're right. I guess the solution can be kept until the OP clearly states if using label/ref and hyperref is a requirement.

Comment: @Ruben: No problem for me... I tried first with something similar to your version, than patching and nothing really worked.

Answer (score 1):

This copies the definitions from `report.cls` and adds the changes (there is bunch of them: counter,chapter head commands, chapter unit name (i.e. 'Box')

In order to make it work with `hyperref` and the section command the `\theHsection` and `\thesection` has to be changed as well.

Currently it uses the same `ToC` as the regular `chapter` command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\newcounter{boxchapter}
\renewcommand\theboxchapter{\Alph{boxchapter}}


\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{section}{boxchapter}% Reset the section within BoxChapter 

\newif\if@boxchapter
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\if@boxchapter\theboxchapter.\arabic{section}\else\thechapter.\arabic{section}\fi}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \newcommand{\theHboxchapter}{boxchapter.\arabic{boxchapter}}% 
  \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{
    \renewcommand{\theHsection}{\if@boxchapter\theHboxchapter.\arabic{section}\else\theHchapter.\arabic{section}\fi}
  }{
    \providecommand{\phantomsection}{}
  }
}
\newcommand{\@boxchapapp}{Box}

\xpretocmd{\chapter}{\@boxchapterfalse}{}{}

\newcommand\BoxChapter{%
  \@boxchaptertrue\relax
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \global\@topnum\z@%
  \@afterindentfalse%
  \secdef\@boxchapter\@sboxchapter%
  }
  \def\@boxchapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \refstepcounter{boxchapter}%
    \typeout{\@boxchapapp\space\theboxchapter.}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
    {\protect\numberline{\theboxchapter}#1}%
    \else
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
    \fi
    \chaptermark{#1}%
  % \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  % \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  \if@twocolumn
  \@topnewpage[\@makeboxchapterhead{#2}]%
  \else
  \@makeboxchapterhead{#2}%
  \@afterheading
  \fi}

\def\@makeboxchapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \color{green!60!black}%
        \huge\bfseries \@boxchapapp\space \theboxchapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\def\@boxschapter#1{\if@twocolumn
                   \@topnewpage[\@makesboxchapterhead{#1}]%
                 \else
                   \@makesboxchapterhead{#1}%
                   \@afterheading
                 \fi}
  \def\@makesboxchapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{50\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
      \normalfont
      \interlinepenalty\@M
      \color{green!60!black}%
      \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
      \vskip 40\p@
    }}

\makeatother

%\usepackage{hyperref}



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage

Compare \ref{box::nicebox} and \ref{chapter::foo} and \ref{box::nicetoo}

\BoxChapter{My nice Box} \label{box::nicebox}

\section{Foo}

\chapter{Foo} \label{chapter::foo}

\section{Foostuff}

\BoxChapter{My other nice Box} \label{box::nicetoo}

\section{Foobarstuff}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Out of interest why does the following not function as it would with a 'traditional' chapter: `\boxchapterfont{\fontsize{24}{27}\selectfont}`?

Comment: @user2568648: There is no command `\chapterfont` or `\boxchapterfont` (yet!)

Comment: A general side note: A bunch of patching is not easier, in my point of view

Comment: I agree. `\chapterfont` exists in the `sectsty` package.

Comment: @user2568648 -- the `sectsty` package defines those macros as hooks to restyle the standard sectioning commands. That does not mean that they exist as a standard core feature. (In fact: if a package defines a command you know that the opposite is the case.) If you want to have a `\chapterfont` or in your case `\boxchapterfont` macro you have to code it into your custom definition.